# What are some tips to solve an environmental-based enigmatic puzzle (EBEP's)?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, strategy

First, some rough definitions:

> **enigmatic puzzle**: a problem where the goal / answer should be well-defined (e.g. enter a certain word or phrase into an form which is accepted; find a clue to a location where a previously designated token can be found). However, the mechanics of extracting this solution are left partially or completely vague, and it’s up to the solver to guess at several interpretations of what the puzzle could mean until one fits.

> **environmental-based puzzle**: a problem where the solver is a "character" in some environment / world (e.g. a video game) where the parameters of the environment dictate the allowable actions by solver. The solver is limited to only allowable actions (in the environment) as potential solutions to the puzzle. Likewise, the solver cannot exit the environment / world where the puzzle resides as a solution.

An "enigmatic environmentally-based puzzle" is simply a mix of the above two definitions.

I'm having trouble thinking of tips I can use to solve EBEP's. I thought of some obvious ones from my head, as follows:

- Know of the allowable actions you can take in the environment.
- If all else fails, try all allowable actions you can think of.
- Use the solutions of similar EBEP's as hints / potential solutions.
- Look for things that seem out of place.
- Look for obvious signs of a hint / solution.
- Don't overthink the solution / Occam's razor.
- Combine allowable actions to increase the set of potential solutions.
- Hints may not be close to the actual puzzle itself.
- Look for differences / dissymmetry if likeness or symmetry seems to play a role.

The list above was all I could think of.

Comment: do you have any particular EBEP in mind?

Comment: Are these really enigmatic puzzles? The things you can do in, say, Portal 2, are *very* strictly defined. Move, jump, fire portal, press button, pick up / drop object.

Comment: Perhaps Portal 2 was a bad example.  A better example would be the three tree puzzle in Breath of the Wild.  You have to shoot down the apples in the trees such that all the trees have the same ammont of apples.  Yet, there is no indication of that being the solution to the puzzle. The only clue in this case is that two trees have 4 apples and one tree has one, where the trees, not including the number of apples, look identical. @Deusovi